# The name does not exist in the current context razor netcore

Tags: asp.net, validation, razor-2

I wanna to learn and add validation to my code but I have this error. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms
I learn from this. And add info from that to my ContosoUniversity based Project

```
@page
@model Proj_s.Pages.Projects.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    {
        if (IsPost)
        {
            string companyname = Request.Form["companyname"];
            string contactname = Request.Form["contactname"];
         //   int employeecount = Request.Form["employees"].AsInt();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change it? I use VS2017 with ASP.NET Web Pages 2

Comment: "ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)" is not the same as "ASP.NET MVC". Find a tutorial which matches the technology and framework you're actually using, or change your project to match the tutorial.

Comment: OK. I do not use MVC. I use Razor.. And this project is Razor as mine,

Comment: I don't see anything in that tutorial requiring you to put `@page
@model Proj_s.Pages.Projects.CreateModel` at the start. Where did that come from? AFAIK ASP.NET Web Pages do not have the concept of a model, however "ASP.NET Core Razor Pages" do. Again a slightly different technology. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page I realise all these slightly-different frameworks can be a bit confusing but it does pay to check very carefully what exactly you are using.

Comment: It come from ContosoUniversity project also using razor . Yes! I use .netcore!

Comment: Ok well in that case again you're using the wrong tutorial. Look at the link I gave instead.

Comment: Thanks. I would try.

Comment: I see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation Is [] only one option? like  [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$"), StringLength(5)] What if I want made my own rules?

Comment: yeah it's just an example. The whole tutorial is just an example...that's the point of a tutorial. You can write whatever you like (as long as it's valid), including changing the regular expression, or using some other kind of validation rule. There are other kinds of `[...]` attributes which go on properties, methods and classes too, to do all sorts of things, no doubt you'll come across them as you get more into it. It's even possible to write your own for certain things, by inheriting the standard base classes, e.g. to create your own completely custom validation attribute.

Comment: but how? I wanna program it. is there any program example for netcore?

Comment: program what? you didn't tell me what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: for example I have two fields with datetype. Begin_Date and End_Date. I wanna check that End_Date always bigger then Begin_Date

Comment: You ought to create a new question for this and set out your requirements clearly. Also do some research first in case the answer is already online. The idea will be very similar across .NET Core, MVC, all the frameworks, this is similar in all of them. There are also Nuget packages available already which allow for custom and flexible validation rules, e.g. ExpressiveAnnotations. You can look up whether they have a version for .NET Core. Others exist too if you search around, which might meet your requirements, before you go down the road of making your own. It's a common-enough requirement.